# Why the current through a resonant tunnel diode drops when the bound state goes below the conduction band?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, resonance, electronic-band-theory, quantum-tunneling

The IV curve of a resonant tunneling diode is N-shaped. The rise in current flow happens because the bound state (the energy state in the well) enters the thermal area of the conductor ($\mu_1 + 10k_BT$).

1. Why does the current ***drop*** when this bound state is lowered below the conduction band? Shouldn't it still contribute to the current while within $\mu_1 - 10k_BT$?
2. In the image below, why the current rises again at elevated bias, if the bound state is below the conduction band (and no additional bound state is present)?

[image: IV-Curve of a double barrier RTD]
([source](http://userweb.eng.gla.ac.uk/douglas.paul/RTD.html))

Comment: Hint - the device name has both 'resonant' and 'tunnel' in it. How will that effect operation?

Comment: @JonCuster, would you mind to elaborate?

Comment: The resonant tunnel diode is a slight tweak on a normal tunnel diode. The tunneling efficiency is a product of two tunneling events. As the bound state moves below the conduction band, the tunneling probability drops like a rock - there is not a state for the conduction electrons to tunnel into (it isn't resonant anymore).  Tunneling from the resonant state to the right isn't as constrained - it just means the electron is injected into any empty state, and will rapidly thermalize down.

Comment: @JonCuster, could you please clarify why: "As the bound state moves below the conduction band, there is not a state for the conduction electrons to tunnel into"?

Comment: There has to be an appropriate landing place.  Since energy needs to be conserved, if the bound state is not level with the conduction band on the right (within a few kT to account for thermal fluctuations in the conduction band only), than there can be no overlap in the tunneling integral.  No overlap, no tunneling.

Comment: As a followup to Jon Custer: The tunneling condition can also be fulfilled, if the energies match after the emission of a phonon. Phonon replica of the original peaks can often be seen in measurements.